# Can we use cookie session id value in the body of the request?

Tags: web-application, session-management

A tester mark this as a vulnerability in the web application that a session id is in the post request instead of cookie header.

Comment: If a tester has marked this as a vulnerability, they need to explain what it leaves you vulnerable to.

Comment: What sort of authentication scheme are you using? Is it a traditional random session id? Is there a reason for putting it in the body?

Comment: One issue is that you can't mark it as HTTP-only if it's in the body.

Comment: You mean in response?

Comment: Revealing sessionID in any request using GET query string or POST body is treated as vulnerability (rather minor severity). But how serious is this (severity), it depends on other checks of the app. And I agree with Andres - using session cookies without "httponly" flag is like asking for trouble.